# Xpath Scrub of Website Incomplete Results

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, web-crawler

I am trying to use the Google Spreadsheet function "importXML" to pull in all links and titles from a Khan Academy Website:

https://www.khanacademy.org/commoncore/grade-HSA-A-SSE

So far I have tried:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.khanacademy.org/commoncore/grade-HSA-A-SSE", "//a[@class='standard-preview']")
```

It brings in 29 results, but not all of the "a" elements with class "standard-preview".  On the webpage, there are many more elements with that class than just the 29 results.

How do I grab all the elements with the class "standard-preview".  Why would my xpath not return some of the values?

My spreadsheet is below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP-WMnoCYzG38VyT_0tYpdblSKjNGvDpa8dRMnraQ7w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share a couple elements that are on that page - that are not coming in?

Comment: I think you have them all. If you go to view source and do find for 'a class="standard-preview" ' you get a count of 29.

Comment: Hmm interesting.  When I do a search for the class "standard-preview" I get 83 results.

Comment: If you look at the webpage, what I'm trying to scrape is the lesson titles and their hyperlinks.  They are the main content of the page.  One person suggested that the page's content may be dynamically loaded and that Google's function "importXML" does not wait for the dynamic content to be loaded before it runs.